# Running an async function with a limited number of threads in julia

Tags: julia

How do you make a function run async or with Threads when you have started julia with say 16 threads, but you only want to run 4 threads at once for this method?

```
for name in names
   for age in ages
       @async runtask()
       Threads.@spawn runtask()
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`@async` does not use threading mechanism. Rather than that it creates an asynchronous task (coroutine, similar to green threads).

The macro `@async` does not have concurrency level, however you can limit the number of concurrent tasks by using `asyncmap` which for the interlnal loop in your code would look like this:

```
asyncmap(runtask, ages; ntasks=2)
```

Note that `runtask` would get the `age` as it parameter.

Comment: Right, I think I mean using Threads then, instead of async.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I came up with using a Semaphore.

```
semaphore = Base.Semaphore(min(4, Threads.nthreads()))

@sync for name in names
    for age in ages
        Threads.@spawn begin
            # Acquire the semaphore, blocking if necessary
            acquire(semaphore)

            runtask()

            # Release the semaphore
            release(semaphore)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: A problem is for large names and ages it mixes up the order due to a race with starting all of the threads at once.  I guess i could sleep but is that the only way?